# how to derive from private key to public key in math

Tags: algorithm, cryptography, rsa, private

I am gonna write down formulas that I know and use to generate RSA keys.

1. we choose `p`, `q`
2. `N = p*q`
3. `f(n)` = `(p-1)(q-1)`
4. choose e such as

- 1 < e < f(n)
- coprime with N, f(n)

5. choose d  so that `d * e (mod f(n) ) = 1`

---

That's it. With these, if we have `p=2` and `q=7`,  I succesfully get `d=11` and `e=5` which is correct.

Now Imagine, that I only have private key which is `(11,14)` (`d=11, N=14`). How do I get `e=5`. I understand that with `d` and `N`, you can't directly get `e`, but as RSA works, it tries different variants of `e` , then checks and if it's valid, that's how you get public key from private key.

Can anyone explain to me what steps should I take here to figure out what `e` could be and then from those, which `e` should I choose ?

Comment: IMO more suitable for https://crypto.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Please remove your post at the originating site when asking on another [se] site. [Cross posting](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/91982/1172) is generally [frowned upon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu), as you get two different sets of comments and answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can't technically derive the public exponent from the private exponent and the modulus.  That would make RSA broken, because it's the same problem as deriving the private exponent from the public exponent and the modulus.

In practice, though, there are only a few public exponents used by the vast majority of RSA implementations, so you can just try them all.  Usually the public exponent is a Fermat prime: 3, 5, 17, 257, or 65537, with 65537 being the most common.